# How to echo out the correct date format

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I have written this add_action snippet in my functions.php file in WordPress. The event date is echoing out successfully, but I am struggling to find the right final bit of code so that it echos in the format ('d M Y'). I just get the basic date string at the moment i.e. 20181225

Can anyone help me to complete this, thank you?

```
add_action( 'dfbm_post_meta_before', function( $post, $featured )   
{
  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'event_date',true);     
} , 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, using PHP's date time

```
echo (new DateTime(get_post_meta($post->ID,'event_date',true)))->format('d M Y');
```

Output

```
echo (new DateTime('20181225'))->format('d M Y');

25 Dec 2018
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfb3f827a49faa61bee392a7abac8a84519c5df8)

Comment: Many thanks !!  I am just beginning with PHP and trying to apply it to real life . But had brain freeze on this..

Answer (score 0):

using simple date() function:

```
echo date('d M Y', '20181225');
```

Comment: yours gives `22 Aug 1970`, you have to use `date('d M Y', str_to_time('20181225'))` and even then it may not like that date format.